How do I open the application after installing? android java
I am making a Java Android application, my user wants after installing the application to open automatically without the user opening it and the user also wants to auto permission gmaps and run in the background service.
Currently I can do the background service and auto permission, but I can't open the application automatically when the user has installed the application.
I think that won't work, because the user has to open the application at least once, so that it can then run in the background service.
Are there any suggestions for dealing with this?
is there a demo for an example?

For the security reason android won't allow app to open automatically.

In order to ensure the safety and satisfaction of its users, Android forbids apps from opening by themselves after downloading. It is designed so that people can have control over what operates on their devices.
But there are a workarounds:
1. Root your Phone
By rooting the device.
then execute command by connecting mobile to your system using shell script

adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.ActivityName

2. Use MDM
Using MDM (Mobile Device Management) it allows automatically install apps.

If you talk about this at organisational level then,
there are websites which provide this type of services like.
https://www.manageengine.com/?pos=MDMPlus&loc=MElogo
https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/android-mdm-solution/
https://soti.net/solutions/mobile-device-management/
